# Why can't the absolute value of a state function be determined?

Tags: thermodynamics, units

What do we mean by 'the absolute value of a state function cannot be determined'?

I have been told that pressure, temperature, and volume are state functions. Though I understand that these quantities fit the definition of a state function (that it is independent of the path taken), I do not understand how their absolute values are indeterminable.

For example, don't we say that the temperature this morning is 12°C or the volume of this container is 1 litre?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Because I can arbitrarily add 5 J/mol to the Gibbs free energy of an element and that changes nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Note first that pressure, temperature and volume are usually regarded as [state variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_variable), not [state functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_function).

State function is any function of the state variables, and the claim in the OP is, strictly speaking, invalid, as, e.g., if we talk about temperature or pressure (e.g., expressed via an ideal gas law.) However, if term *state function* is used in a narrower sense, meaning [*thermodynamic potential*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_potential), then these are defined by their differential forms (aka [*fundamental thermodynamic relation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation)), like
$$
dU = TdS - pdV,
$$
that is we know only the differential of the function, but not its value - which can be determined by integration only up to an additive constant.